# script doesn't work when I use == 0, but with > 0, its not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made this script to check is the `magazineSize` from `Gun` script is equal to `0`, if yes  I need to disable `weaponRecoilCS` and `cameraRecoilCS`, but its not working, but when I try using:

if `(gunCS.magazineSize > 0)` the scripts get turned off, and when I change it back to: `(gunCS.magazineSize == 0)` nothing happen the scripts does not turn off.

and this is the script that I am using:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RecoilDisabler : MonoBehaviour
{
    WeaponRecoil weaponRecoilCS;
    CameraRecoil cameraRecoilCS;
    Gun gunCS;

    [SerializeField] GameObject gun;
    [SerializeField] GameObject camRecoilObj;

    void Awake()
    {
        gunCS = gun.GetComponent<Gun>();
        weaponRecoilCS = gun.GetComponent<WeaponRecoil>();
        cameraRecoilCS = camRecoilObj.GetComponent<CameraRecoil>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (gunCS.magazineSize == 0)
        {
            weaponRecoilCS.enabled = false;
            cameraRecoilCS.enabled = false;
        }
        else if (gunCS.magazineSize < 0)
        {
            weaponRecoilCS.enabled = true;
            cameraRecoilCS.enabled = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of magazineSize?

Comment: In your text you say if > on your code you say if < 0 why would you enable when less than zero and stop when zero. Maybe thats why?

Comment: I assume that magazineSize is the number of shots left? Then a negative value makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

## **You can try:**

<=

Since > 0 makes it work even if its higher than 0.

Comment: <= is no different than ==

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert to appropriate data type and then do the comparison, I have imagined that **magazineSize** is Integer so I have converted the **gunCS.magazineSize** to Integer and then do the comparison, just like this

```
int magazineSize = 0;
int.TryParse(gunCS.magazineSize.ToString(), out magazineSize);
```

Now, if you check you should get the result you want,

```
if (magazineSize == 0)
        {
            // YOUR CODE FOR EQUAL TO ZERO
        }
        else
        {
            // YOUR CODE FOR NOT EQUAL TO ZERO
        }
```

just like the following:

```
int magazineSize = 0;
int.TryParse(gunCS.magazineSize.ToString(), out magazineSize); 

if (magazineSize == 0)
{
    // YOUR CODE FOR EQUAL TO ZERO
}
else
{
    // YOUR CODE FOR NOT EQUAL TO ZERO
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but I figured it out its just I took the wrong int

Comment: That is great news @SamiSalama, glad to hear that, that is why I converted to Int, I was afraid of the data type, it happen for me too a lot of time :)

Comment: ToString + Parse is about the worst way to convert to integer. Just use Convert.ToInt32, unless it is already an int (which is not known at this point)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I just wanted to let him know if he is checking the right data type, this is not about converting something from i.e float -> toString -> int -> ... 
also, int.TryParse is much better than Convert.ToInt32 because here you can't convert string to int32, 

can you try Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32("Hans")); you will get System.FormatException and your program crash. 

So, if you are using this in your programs, in my opinion, change them to <T>.TryParse()

Best regards.